# Going from wavepacket to wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, terminology, fourier-transform

Suppose we have a one-dimensional wave packet

$$\varphi(p)=A\Theta[(\hbar/d)-|p-p_0|].
$$
I want to, at first, determine the constant of normalization, and the wavefunction $\psi(x)$. However, there are a few things here I am quite unclear about.

I am a mathematician with zero prior background in physics trying to learn basic quantum mechanics. So far I got around Schrödingers Equation, looked a bit at probability distributions, the Ehrenfest theorem, further onto the Harmonic Oscillator with tunneling effects, potential steps etc. So I kind of know wavefunctions. However, I am not sure how to understand this wave-$\textit{packet}$.

How do I go from -packet to -function, in the general case? And what are these values $d$ and $p_0$ in the above? In the text for the posed problem these are not specified, so I assume it is quite obvious given you have seen wave packets before.

Comment: Wavepacket is just a special case of wavefunction. See e.g. [the wikipedia article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet). What exactly text are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

The Schrödinger's form of the wave equation is an expression of kinetic energy + potential energy = total energy. A wave function is one specific solution to this wave equation.

A wave packet is a specific collection of solutions to the wave equation. Think of it as more than one photon or more than one particle behaving as a wave, all traveling in a collection. Each photon/wave-particle has an uncertainty on its position in the collection. The collection satisfies the Heisenberg uncertainty principle on position and momentum. Since momentum is related to wavelength, each photon/wave-particle in the collection has a different wavelength. The sum of all solutions in the packet is equivalent to the sum of a series of sin/cosine waves of different wavelength. This generates a packet.

Here is an example of the generation of a wave packet using 1000 cosine waves. Each sequence shows a larger uncertainty in wavelength for each successive wave in the packet.

[image: sequence to generate a wave packet]

The equation to generate the wave packet (wp) is below.

$$ wp = \sum \cos\left(x/(\lambda + n\Delta \lambda)\right) $$